# Para que serve este conteúdo no Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou utilizando o [Bootstrap](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css) na versão v3.0 e analisando o arquivo `CSS`, encontrei esse trecho:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Gostaria de saber, qual a utilização `*`.

Na [versão corrente do Bootstrap (3.3.4)](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css), ele está dentro de um `@media Print{}`, assim:

```
@media print {
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
            box-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

Gostaria de saber, para que serve esse código?

Comment: `*` seleciona todos os elementos. Sua dúvida é só isso ou é sobre o `:before` e `:after` também?

Comment: @Lucas no caso, é somente sobre o *  mesmo.

Comment: @Lucas coloca como resposta p/ pergunta ser encerrada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viva!

O símbolo * representa todos os elementos da tua página HTML.

Por exemplo, se tu pretendesses adicionar um backgroud preto em todos os elementos da tua página HTML poderias utilizar o seguinte CSS:

```
* {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

O símbolo * também permite que seleccionar todos os elementos dentro de outro elemento, por exemplo:

```
div * {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

No exemplo acima apenas os elementos que estivessem dentro de uma div é que ficariam com o background preto.

Relativamente à tua dúvida sobre o funcionamento do **@media print {}**, significa que aquele css só é aplicado quando a página está em mode pré-visualização da impressão.

Podes consultar mais sobre os vários tipo de @media no seguinte link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/CSS/@media